# Cannot run solc

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, solc, ubuntu

After following the install instructions here:

http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-solidity.html

When I try and run solc, I get the following error:

```
solc: error while loading shared libraries: libjsoncpp.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have uninstalled and re-installed libjsoncpp1

I have unistalled and re-installed solc a number of times

I am stumped!

Running Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: please read this https://github.com/ethereum/webthree/issues/105

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the link - it helped.

Eventually managed to delete all the symlinks, removed the correct libraries, re-installed and then finally closed the terminal and re-opened a new terminal.

Once I did that it worked.  It appeared as though the terminal was keeping a symlink in cache.

Comment: The problem came about because I upgraded ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04.  Its worth re-installing geth and solidity for 16.04